# React-Native Android PushNotifications

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native

Do we have PushNotification support for Android platform? Documentation shows iOS support (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html) nothing for Android.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally used this but this looks like it hooks up to Google's cloud messaging platform which is what is used for Push Notifications on Android.

https://github.com/oney/react-native-gcm-android

Answer (score 1):

I've build this solution using OneSignal ([link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-overview)). There is a [react-native plugin](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal) for it as well with iOS and Android support. You'll only have the same API for both platforms. Also it is free to use!